# Can a 600V->208V transformer become a 600V->240V transformer by shortening the secondary coil?

Tags: transformer

If I have a 3 phase 600V to 208V step down transformer, can I shorten the secondary coils to turn it into a 600V to 240V?

In theory it seems as it should work:

```
Vs = (Ns/Np) * Vp
```

How about in practice?

If it is possible, can the transformer be reversed to produce 600V from a 240V source?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the secondary voltage, you require more turns on the secondary winding, not fewer.

Transformers do work "backwards", but I've heard they may be slightly less efficient when used backwards.

Comment: Efficiency should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can reduce the number of windings by shortening colis but you would need to mess around with the isolation and that you definitely do not want to do.
A transformer can be used "backwards" if current and voltage ratings are met.
Think about your statement about reducing the numbers of windings on the secondary side though and look again at the equation.